# How to plot a linear regression model and a poisson regression model on the same plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, regression, linear-regression, poisson

I am working with a simple set of data that deals with the age of an elephant (explanatory) and how many successful mating partners each elephant has had (response). I have found two models: one is a linear regression model and the second is a Poisson regression model. I would like to make a plot of matings vs age and then superimpose both the models onto this same plot. Then I would compare which one fits better visually. I have been messing around with ggplot, just the regular plot function, some lines stuff. I really have no idea how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume by a "linear regression model" you mean an OLS model with normal residuals (a la `lm`), as opposed to a Poisson linear regression model where the response `Y ~ Poisson)`. Those two models make very different assumptions, and are **not interchangeable**. For a start, one model assumes a continuous response variable (OLS), the other a discrete response variable (Poisson). Wanting to compare them (you can't!) suggests a more fundamental issue with understanding how to model your data and what the underlying assumptions are. Perhaps this is a better fit for Cross Validated?

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to visualize, then it's quite easy to use `predict(, type = "response")` as a way to show the resulting model. I use `glm` for both models, but technically, `lm`  would also work for the linear model:

```
set.seed(11)
# sample size
n <- 50
# regression coefficients
beta0 <- 0
beta1 <- 0.04
beta2 <- 0.05
# generate covariate values
x <- round(runif(n=n, min=1, max=40))
# compute mu's
mu <- exp(beta0 + beta1 * x + beta2^2 * x)
# generate Y-values
y <- rpois(n = n, lambda=mu)
# data set
data <- data.frame(matings=y, age=x)
data



fitLM <- glm(matings ~ age, data, family = gaussian(link = "identity"))
fitPOIS <- glm(matings ~ age, data, family = poisson(link = "log"))
AIC(fitLM, fitPOIS) # poisson has lower AIC

newdat <- data.frame(age = seq(1,40,0.1))
newdat$predLM <- predict(fitLM, newdata = newdat, type = "response")
newdat$predPOIS <- predict(fitPOIS, newdata = newdat, type = "response")

plot(matings ~ age, data)
lines(predLM ~ age, newdat, col = 2)
lines(predPOIS ~ age, newdat, col = 4)
legend("topleft", legend = c("lm", "poisson"), col = c(2,4), lty = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: This is not a good answer in my opinion; it avoids the critical issue, which is that OP can't and shouldn't compare an OLS and Poisson regression model. OLS (or a GLM with a gaussian identity link) assumes a continuous response variable. A Poisson model assumes a discrete dependent variable.  Results from both models cannot be (visually) compared. A better answer (which should probably be posted on Cross Validated rather than here) would explain *why* those two models are not comparable. Showing how this can be done in R sadly teaches bad statistical practice and un-critical thinking.

Comment: [continued] Or in other words: Just because you *can* visualise something in R doesn't mean you *should*!

Comment: @MauritsEvers - I think you should check again at what the OP is asking for. Just because that is not the question that you think they should ask is no reason to downvote. The point is that you *can* compare them visually, even if this is not the way to choose a model.

Comment: No. As I said in my last comment: Just because you can *do* something in R doesn't mean you *should*. It makes no sense statistically to compare results from an OLS and Poisson regression model. Wanting to do so suggests a bigger issue (that of misunderstanding what these models do). *That* is the issue that should be addressed.  This is a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). [...]

Comment: [continued] Stack Overflow is about building a database of useful & meaningful questions and answers not only for one person but for the community. Your "answer" addresses the wrong issue, teaches bad practice and is therefore not a good answer.